# Materialize CSS Autocomplete using Flask and MySQL

Tags: jquery, python, mysql, flask, materialize

What I am trying to do is creating a Search Bar with autocomplete functionality using Materialize CSS. Which I have working using a simple array. Working code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete" >

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: {
        "Dog": null,
        "Bear": null,
        "Bull": null,
        "Cat": null
    }
});
});
</script>
```

What I would like to do is instead of using the array in my script to go back to my MySQL database using Flask. I have been experimenting with some flask routes with no luck.

```
@app.route('/autocomplete', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def autocomplete():
if request.method == 'POST':
    query = request.form['query']
    try:

        with db.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "SELECT short_name, name FROM table WHERE name LIKE %s"
            cursor.execute(sql('%' + query + '%'))
            result = cursor.fetchall()
    finally:
        a = 2
        return render_template("results.html", search_result=result)
else:

    return "ooops"
```

Has any one figured out if this is even possible?

Comment: The expected result you want is " when a user types then make a post call to flask back end and get the relevant results" right?

Comment: @Pradeepb That is correct. [Example] (https://icefox0801.github.io/materialize-autocomplete/examples/) however I just want to query the MySQL database.

Comment: I checked a lot and could not find if materialize CSS supports ajax calls for autocomplete. I would suggest using jquery-UI autocomplete(i have used it in one project and it work flawlessly)

Comment: @Pradeepb Do you have an example you can share?

Answer (score 0):

The below example is using `Jquery-UI`. include [this](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js) in your HTML file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax('/autocomplete', {
                    'method': 'GET',
                    'data': request
                }).done(function (data) {
                    response(data['items']);
                }).fail(function () {
                    console.log('fail');
                });
            },
            minLength: 3, // minimum Length of characters
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks, I am getting a TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
in my flask portion of the code. Any chance you have an example of your python/flask code?

Comment: Here is [mine](https://pastebin.com/1mWd8Luk) Where I get "cursor.execute(sql, ('%' + search + '%'))
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType"

Comment: Check if value is passibg from front end to backend

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: I cannot check that as I get the error on running of the project. When I try to pass the input I basically get nothing for a response

Comment: I meant to check in chrome developer tools. If the GET call sending any values?

Comment: I am getting http://localhost:5000/autocomplete 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) when loading the page from the developer tools. Same error happens in postman